# Google calendars django website

Tags: django, google-calendar-api

I am trying to display and maintain a separate Google calendar for each user on my Django website. I also want to synchronize each users' Google calendar on the website, with their actual Google Calendar so that events are maintained and displayed not just on the website, but when they log into their Google Calendar through their Google account.

I have no idea how to approach this. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you are going to have to do is look into [OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth) for authentication this will allow you to access your users Google Calendars.   You will just need to save the refresh Token for each user then you will be able to access the information again by requesting a new access Token.

After that you should look into the [Google Calendar API reference](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/)

There is also a Google Client library for python that will probably make things a lot easer.  [Google APIs Client Library for Python](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/).

I don't have any django or python experience so I cant help you out with any code.  But if you get stuck just ask a new question on Stack.  These links should at least give you an idea of where to start.

Comment: thanks for the help. any idea how i can send a user to the Google authorization page and back to my website through the Django framework?